# C++ Template Terminology

Tags: c++

If I have the following

```
template<class T> print_all(vector<T> const & collection);
```

What would you call T in context of the declaration? i.e. Would you say that T is the argument for vector  const & collection? i.e It satisfies a vector as the type is closed?

Keen to find out what the actual terminology is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`T` is a *template parameter* of the function template `print_all`, which is used as a *template argument* for the class template `vector`.

Comment: Would you say that vector is dependent on T?

Comment: @BlairDavidson You can say it, but it's not standard terminology.

Comment: Yes, the type `vector<T>` is dependent on `T`.  This affects name resolution during the compilation process (because `std::vector` could be, and actually is, specialized for some types).